# Sum of variables of a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, concentration-of-measure, large-deviation-theory

I have the sequence $X_1, X_2,...X_n$ as a martingale, each of which is bounded. Now I want to explore some upper bound for the sum $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$, e.g., the format like Hoeffding inequality or Berstein inequality. Any method or conclusions suggestions for this? I have no idea at all and can't find any related conclusions.

Comment: Maybe this can be what you are looking for https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality. But the assumption should be that $X_n$ is a martingale difference sequence.

Comment: Thank you. I have considered that but the assumption is different as you pointed out, which makes it difficult to apply it to my problem.